# TextView setText does not work after introduce the ExecutorService

Tags: java, android, concurrency, textview, java.util.concurrent

I met this problem when I want to use **ExecutorService**. I simply create a **Button** and a **TextView**. The behavior I want to approach is that when pressing the Button, the TextView changes to the text "Napping...". And another thread starts, which will sleep for some random time (milliseconds). After sleeping, a string will be returned and the TextView will be set to that.

Here is the Callable class that will be used for SingleThreadExecutor.

```
package com.example.simpleasynctask;

import java.util.Random;
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;

public class MyWorkThread implements Callable<String> {
    @Override
    public String call() throws Exception {
        Random r = new Random();
        int n = r.nextInt(11);
        int s = n*200;
        try {
            Thread.sleep(s);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return "Awake at last after sleeping for " + s + " milliseconds!";
    }
}
```

And here is the function that will be called when pressing the button

```
 public void startTask(View view) throws Exception{
        mTextView.setText(R.string.napping); // it does not work
        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
        Future future =  executorService.submit(mCallable);
        executorService.shutdown();
        mTextView.setText((String) future.get()); // it works

    }
```

The strange behavior is that the first line in this function does not work. It just skips that line and waits for the result returned from the other thread. See the two pictures below.
[image]

[image]

However, the "Napping..." text can be set if I simply remove all but the first line from the *startTask*. Can anyone help me? Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1):

The Android [Handler](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler) is better is suited for purposes like this, use it like:

```
public void startTask(View view) {
    long sleeptime = 10 * 1000;//10 seconds
    mTextView.setText("Napping...");
    new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            mTextView.setText("Awake at last after sleeping for " + sleeptime + " milliseconds!"); 
        }
    }, sleeptime);
}
```

or you can just do:

```
public void startTask1(View view) {
    long sleeptime = 10 * 1000;//10 seconds
    mTextView.setText("Napping"); 
    view.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            mTextView.setText("Awake at last after sleeping for " + sleeptime + " milliseconds!");
        }
    }, sleeptime);
}
```

Comment: It seems your method is to sleep UI thread. I am new to the concurrency and try to learn how to handle multiple threads.  And I am confused about how does the problem could happen. Hope someone can explain that.

Comment: @FrederickLI No it will not sleep or freeze the UI thread, you can interact with the app while this runs. Android requires that all UI updates happen in the UI thread or else it will throw exceptions, the above ensures that the view update will always happen on the UI thread.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. What I meant is that postDelayed can execute a Runnable after a certain time period. In my case, this works like sleeping a new thread. However, there is still one thread running, right? What I want to learn is the concurrency in Android. Anyway, thank you very much.

Comment: @FrederickLI Well I am not sure what specifically you are trying to understand here but an Android app has to run on the UI or main thread so the UI/main thread has to keep running. Handler does not create any new thread. You can learn about Java Concurrency and Multithreading [here](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-concurrency/index.html)